# mysqli_connect() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php, mysqli

> Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 2 to be string, object
>   given in C:\wamp\www\social\includes\acceso.php on line 56 line 56:

```
mysqli_connect($database_conexionredsocial, $conexionredsocial);
```

I need help with this. I would really appreciate if anyone came with the solution.

Comment: Hi, try to var_dump both $LoginRS__query and $conexionredsocial. Check if anyone of them might have different data type.

Comment: Help: navigate to `php.net/mysqli_connect`, read up the list of parameters for ths function, implement them in the proper order

Comment: What part of the error messages are unclear? Read the documentation and check your parameters. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: What is `$conexionredsocial`? What is `$LoginRS__query`?  `mysql_error` doesn't work with `mysqli`.

Comment: You need to switch `$LoginRS__query` and `$conexionredsocial` :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `mysqli_connect()` function expects the second parameter (well, all its parameters actually) to be **string**. Whereas a value of another type has been supplied.

So here goes a little checklist to follow in order to fix this error:

- first of all make sure there was no confusion made. For example, given in the code from the question only two parameters were supplied for the function that expects at least three, I have a feeling that `mysqli_connect()` has been confused with `mysqli_query()`. In this case just change the function name (and the order of variables, as `mysqli_query()` expects the connection *object* as the first parameter).
- if it's not the case, and you are positively sure you are calling `mysqli_connect()` on purpose, you must verify the certain variable the error message points at. In this particular case it's the second parameter but in your case it could be anything, refer to your actual error message for the number. In the present case, for example, it means that `$conexionredsocial` is not a string. As it can be seen on the [corresponding manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), the second parameter for `mysqli_connect()` should be the a `username`. So you have to double-check that a variable provided as a second parameter contains a correct username. It would be also a good idea to double check all other variables as well.

Given that most likely such an error is the result of incorrect connection code, please refer to the bullet-proof connection code taken from my article  [How to connect with mysqli properly](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect):

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, $charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
unset($host, $db, $user, $pass, $charset); // we don't need them anymore
```

Simply edit variables to make them contain your actual database credentials, store this code in a file and then simply include this file in the every script that needs a database connection.

You are also kindly welcome to read the article linked above, as it has an in-depth explanation for all the options used in the code and some hints that could make your database interactions with mysqli much simpler.

Comment: i didt it but it still appears the mysqli_query warming .. (the mysqli_connect error disapear) but the other one doesnt . if you can come with a solution i will check the message as a right answer. so please help me

Comment: How does getting rid of the connect line fix the error? You need to fix the error.